# Kerning/spacing in Profile Activity (mobile)

Tags: support, bug, profile-page

In the profile -> summary tab of one's account (when you are not logged in), when the "top tag" and "next privilege" combination are displayed there is no kerning/spacing between the names for tracking of these activities from a mobile browser (iOS Safari 13.0.4).

#### Landscape

[image]

#### Portrait

[image]

If one is logged in, it is working as expected:

[image]

Model this layout for public view (but remove points as noted):

[image]

Comment: The screenshots are missing [freehand red circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775) (I am serious). It would also be nice with frames, especially for the ones with a white background.

Comment: No repro on both Chrome for Windows (mobile layout) and Chrome for Android. You might want to [edit] the question and include details about the browser that you're using.

Comment: The browser ver is added and an additional screenshot if it may further help.